# What object is produced by ternary operator in C++?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, stdoptional

The following program

```
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::optional<int> a;
    constexpr bool x = true;

    const std::optional<int> & b = x ? a : std::nullopt;
    std::cout << (&a == &b);

    const std::optional<int> & c = x ? a : (const std::optional<int> &)std::nullopt;
    std::cout << (&a == &c);

    const std::optional<int> & d = x ? a : (const std::optional<int>)std::nullopt;
    std::cout << (&a == &d);
}
```

prints `010` even in case of compiler optimization:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/asTrzdE3c

Could you please explain why it is so, and what is the difference between seemingly identical 3 cases?

Comment: See __Conditional operator__ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other as it's about 2 pages of "_if-this-then-that"_

Comment: As another datapoint, if you compare the optionals directly (rather than taking their address) it prints `111`

Comment: In a laymen words, ternary operator will return an object of a type to which both operands are implicitly convertible (this is why it is used behind the scenes in the metafunction `std::common_type`). If both operands are of the common type, you will get a reference to the one selected. If not, a temporary object of the required type will be created. This is the case in your first and third example.

Comment: @SergeyA Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I felt it is a bit short on normative to be an answer, but I can post it if people think it is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to undesund what is the type of ternary operator result.

```cpp
x ? a : std::nullopt;
```

Here `a` is variable which can be reference and `std::nullopt` is something which is implicitly converted to optional of matching type (here `std::optional<int>`).
So conversion of `std::nullopt` ends with creation of temporary value. To match type `a` is also copied.

So ternary operator deduces type to be a value of type `std::optional<int>` which becomes a temporary object. New instance of `std::optional<int>` is created.

Now `const auto &` is able to prolong lifetime of temporaries. So `b` is reference to `std::optional<int>` which is a temporary of prolonged lifetime.

`d` is same scenario, but it is more explicit.

`c`  has `(const std::optional<int> &)std::nullopt` which is creates temporary object of `std::optional<int>` with prolonged lifetiem. Here ternary operator has as argument something what is `std::optional<int>&` and `const std::optional<int>&` so it is able to pass first arguments reference return type.

See what [cppinsights generates](https://cppinsights.io/s/22e78830) with your code:

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::optional<int> a = std::optional<int>();
  constexpr const bool x = true;
  const std::optional<int> & b = x ? std::optional<int>(a) : std::optional<int>(std::nullopt_t(std::nullopt));
  std::cout.operator<<((&a == &b));
  const std::optional<int> & c = x ? a : static_cast<const std::optional<int>>(std::optional<int>(std::nullopt_t(std::nullopt)));
  std::cout.operator<<((&a == &c));
  const std::optional<int> & d = (x ? std::optional<int>(a) : static_cast<const std::optional<int>>(std::optional<int>(std::nullopt_t(std::nullopt))));
  std::cout.operator<<((&a == &d));
}
```

Comment: This code (generated by cppinsignt) is not equivalent, it prints ```000```

Comment: tool has bug off by one character. Adding `&` [fixes issue](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1YzEYaMMn).

Answer (score 3):

In a laymen words, ternary operator will return an object of a type to which both operands are implicitly convertible (Tidbit: this is why it is used behind the scenes in the metafunction `std::common_type`).

If both operands are of the common type, you will get a reference to the one selected. If not, a temporary object of the required type will be created. This is the case in your first and third example.